# Measurable rectangles form an algebra [Disproof attempt]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> **Proposition** Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{N})$ be measurable spaces. The family of rectangles: $$\mathcal{R} := \{A \times B : A \in \mathcal{M}, B \in \mathcal{N}\}$$
>   is an algebra, i.e. is closed by finite unions and by complementation.

*Disproof attempt:*

Consider $X = Y =\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{N} = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (borelian $\sigma$-algebra).

Let $A = [0,1] \times [0,1], \ B = [0,1] \times [1,2], \ C = [1,2]\times [0,1]$.

Clearly $A,B,C \in \mathcal{R}$,
but $D = A \cup B \cup C$ is not in $\mathcal{R}$ since do not exist $E \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $F \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $D = E \times F$

---

This attempt is driven by geometric intuition rather that formal reasoning and I did not really prove the last sentence.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are not wrong. It is not an algebra, but a [semi algebra](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Measure_Theory/Basic_Structures_And_Definitions/Semialgebras,_Algebras_and_%CF%83-algebras#Semialgebras).

Comment: It seems correct, but you might want to consider a simpler example: $A=[0,2]\times [0,2]$ and $B=[1,3]\times [1,3]$ also produce $D=A\cup B\not\in \mathcal{R}$. It is good to have the geometric intuition, but, can you prove formally that $D$ cannot be written as a product of two sets $D=E\times F$? (Hint: think about the points in the lower-right corner, which do not belong to $D$ but whose projections belong to $E$ and $F$ respectively)

Comment: @drhab I misread the book. It says that the family of finite unions of rectangles is an algebra. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete your proof: a set $S$ is in the form $A\times B$ if and only if $$(x,y)\in S\wedge (w,z)\in S\implies (x,z)\in S$$ For instance, this fails in your case with pairs $(2,0),\ (0,2)$.